# Jenkins zipfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, zip

I want to do something very simple, in a folder I have a jar file and a folder called scripts that contains scripts. But I can get jenkins zip to do this.

zip dir: 'awsdeploy', exclude: '', glob: '*', 'scripts/*', zipFile: 'SQSToElasticProcessor.zip'

Arguments to "zip" must be explicitly named. @ line 31, column 16.

```
              zip dir: 'awsdeploy', exclude: '', glob: '*', 'scripts/*.*', zipFile: 'SQSToElasticProcessor.zip'
```

Comment: can you share a more detailled pipeline ?

Answer (score 0):

What I am trying to do is zip the following in the folder  awsdeploy:
jarFile
scripts:
script1
script2

So I need to zip up the jar file and the subdirectory scripts

Comment: Thia is not an answer. Either amend your question or add a comment to the comment or the answer. Ans please delete this entry.